# For ListView how to optimize text inside it when it is too longer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, text, ellipsis

For below widget how to optimise Text() widget further when there is longer text included TextOverflow.ellipsis is not working for it.There is combination Column,Row,Listview in my code.How should I optimise text for longer text I have tried using Expanded,Flexible,FittedBox but getting confused how and when to use it.

[image]

```
Widget builddoc(Document doc) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    DocumentsDetails(doc.docId, this.userName)));
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2,
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                )),
            borderOnForeground: true,
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 5,
            child: ListView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Flexible(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.file_copy_rounded,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '${doc.docTitle}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                                      fontSize:
                                          (SizeConfig.screenWidth ?? 0) * 0.033,
                                    ),
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${doc.tokenNo}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                                        fontSize: 1.5 *
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                            0.01),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                        )),
                        AutoSizeText('${doc.docStatus}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                                fontSize: 1.5 *
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                    0.01)),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_right_sharp,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                          size: 25,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Expanded or Flexible widget for see all text or you can try Maxlines and textOverFlow in Text Widget.